# Joomla! no result on query

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla

I have a basic query in Joomla! and I really, really can't figure out why it doesn't return anything:

```
$database =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
$database->setQuery($query);
$result = $database->loadObjectList();
var_dump($result);
die();
```

Query is very, very basic, I know.
It returns $result as null. Thing is, I run this query in a separate .php scrip file (localhost/myscript.php). All other queries in the rest of my website seem to run just fine (including some in other script files like this one).

I've run this query in a terminal and returns what I want. Please, I need some idea :)

Comment: did you include the right classes files ?

Comment: add error checkers at various steps... echo the query then try to print result so that its easy to code debug. Try this also--> echo "Database prefix is : " . $database->getPrefix(); so that you can confirm that your first line is also working

Answer (score 1):

If your trying this in a separate php file (localhost/myscipt.php) as you say, you need the proper classes.  See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459430/include-jfactory-class-in-an-external-php-file-joomla).  The last answer has some details.

However this is not recommended. You should be using [module](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_simple_module) or [plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla_1.5) development all within the framework.

Alternatively, you could use [Jumi](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/1023) which allows you to write any code you want and include it as part of a module. Makes life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is missing a table prefix, you can echo the prefix using `$database->getPrefix();`
also try changing

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `#__my_table`";
```

> NOTE: Joomla uses a placeholder for the prefix, the “`#__`” will be replaced with the correct prefix.